# System is computationally singular due to small numbers in linearHypothesis

Tags: r, regression, numerics, error-message

Ok, so here is the code that demonstrate the problem I am referring to:

```
x1 <- c(0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.0003)
x2 <- c(15000893, 23034340, 3034300, 232332242)
x3 <- c(1,3,5,6)
y <- rnorm( 4 )
model=lm( y ~ x1 + x2 )
model2=lm( y ~ x1 + x3 )
type <- "hc0"
V <- hccm(model, type=type)
sumry <- summary(model)
table <- coef(sumry)
table[,2] <- sqrt(diag(V))
table[,3] <- table[,1]/table[,2]
table[,4] <- 2*pt(abs(table[,3]), df.residual(model), lower.tail=FALSE)
sumry$coefficients <- table
p <- nrow(table)
hyp <- cbind(0, diag(p - 1))
linearHypothesis(model, hyp, white.adjust=type)
```

Note that this is not caused by perfect multicollinearity. 
As you can see, I deliberately set the value of x2 to be very large and the value of x1 to be very small. When this happens, I cannot perform a linearHypothesis test of `model=lm( y ~ x1 + x2 )` on all coefficients being `0`: `linearHypothesis(model, hyp, white.adjust=type)`. R will throw the following error:

```
> linearHypothesis(model, hyp, white.adjust=type)
Error in solve.default(vcov.hyp) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.31795e-23
```

However, when I use `model2=lm( y ~ x1 + x3 )` instead, whose `x3` is not too large compared to `x1`, the linearHypothesis test succeeds:

```
> linearHypothesis(model2, hyp, white.adjust=type)
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
x1 = 0
x3 = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: y ~ x1 + x3

Note: Coefficient covariance matrix supplied.

  Res.Df Df      F Pr(>F)
1      3                 
2      1  2 11.596 0.2033
```

I am aware that this might be caused by the fact that **R** cannot invert matrices whose numbers are smaller than a certain extent, in this case `2.31795e-23`. However, is there a way to circumvent that? Is this the limitation in R or the underlying `C++`?
What is the good practice here? The only method I can think of is to rescale the variables so that they are at the same scale. **But I am also concerned about the amount of information I will lose by dividing everything by their standard errors.**

**In fact, I have 200 variables that are percentages, and 10 variables (including dependent variables) that are large (potentially to the 10^6 scale). It might be troubling to scale them one by one.**

Comment: The problem may be in `hccm`, have you tried using a regular covariance matrix?

Comment: The hccm step passes though